# Line charts in d3.js using d3.chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I want to use `d3.chart()` for the charts I have written already. I found examples of `d3.chart()` for `circle` and `barcharts` but not for `line charts`. My charts are line charts, I need to use following code in `d3.charts()`

```
svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

but am facing problem when try to use like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.chart.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="vis"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


d3.chart("linechart", {

  initialize: function() {
    // create a base scale we will use later.
   var chart = this;
    chart.w = chart.base.attr('width') || 200;
    chart.h = chart.base.attr('height') || 150;
    chart.w = +chart.w;
    chart.h = +chart.h;

   chart.x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, chart.w]);

  chart.y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([chart.h,0]);

  chart.base.classed('line', true);

  this.areas = {};
      chart.areas.lines = chart.base.append('g')
              .classed('lines', true)
              .attr('width', chart.w)
              .attr('height', chart.h)

       chart.line = d3.svg.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return chart.x(d.x);})   
                  .y(function(d) { return chart.y(d.y);});


    this.layer("lines", chart.areas.lines, {
      dataBind: function(data) {
        // update the domain of the xScale since it depends on the data
           chart.y.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.y}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.y})])
            chart.x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));

        // return a data bound selection for the passed in data.
                                    return this.append("path")
                                              .datum(data)
                                              .attr("d", chart.line)
                                              .attr('stroke','#1ABC9C')
                                              .attr('stroke-width','2')
                                              .attr('fill','none');
      },
      insert: function() {

        return null;

      },

    });
  },

  // configures the width of the chart.
  // when called without arguments, returns the
  // current width.
  width: function(newWidth) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return this.w;
    }
    this.w = newWidth;
    return this;
  },

  // configures the height of the chart.
  // when called without arguments, returns the
  // current height.
  height: function(newHeight) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return this.h;
    }
    this.h = newHeight;
    return this;
  },

});

var data = [
{x: 0,y:190},
  {x: 1,y:10},{x: 2,y:40},{x: 3,y:90},
  {x: 4,y:30},{x: 5,y:20},{x: 6,y:10}
];

var chart1 = d3.select("#vis")
  .append("svg")
  .chart("linechart")
  .width(720)
  .height(320)

chart1.draw(data);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

error:

> Uncaught Error: [d3.chart] Layer selection not properly bound.

I have get the line and error as well.

**Note:** Get `d3.chart.min.js` from [this link](https://github.com/misoproject/d3.chart)
Get `d3.v3.min.js` from [this link](http://d3js.org/)

**Updated:** I got answer from @LarsKotthoff answer, but there is different in image. check this links [Before apply D3](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-ap.hipchat.com/29784/201183/Ed2OIA4JwaO6lig/upload.png) and [After apply D3](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-ap.hipchat.com/29784/201183/hCkNgswzmIV6DOQ/upload.png).

Comment: Could you post a complete working example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: I have updated my question, can you have a look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have confused the `insert` and `dataBind` actions -- in the former, you're supposed to append the new elements while the latter only binds the data. With the modifications below, your code works fine for me.

```
dataBind: function(data) {
    // update the domain of the xScale since it depends on the data
       chart.y.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.y}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.y})])
        chart.x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));

    // return a data bound selection for the passed in data.
    return this.selectAll("path").data([data]);
  },
 insert: function() {
    return this.append("path")
              .attr("d", chart.line)
              .attr('stroke','#1ABC9C')
              .attr('stroke-width','2')
              .attr('fill','none');

  }
```

Note that this won't work for several lines -- to do that, change `.data([data])` to `.data(data)` and use a nested array, e.g. `[[{x:0,y:0},...], [{x:1,y:1},...], ...]`.

Comment: After I tried as you said, the line doesn't come smooth but it is working. check these links [Before apply D3](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-ap.hipchat.com/29784/201183/Ed2OIA4JwaO6lig/upload.png) and [After apply D3](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-ap.hipchat.com/29784/201183/hCkNgswzmIV6DOQ/upload.png).

Comment: What do you mean by "before" and "after" D3? Aren't both of these done using D3?

Comment: Can you tell me why the line doesn't come smooth

Comment: I have normal code with simple d3.js not with d3.chart.min.js, there I get smooth line but not with when I use d3.chart.min.js

Comment: I would guess that the CSS you're using is different.

Comment: I don't use separate `.css` file for above code, can you tell me what style should I use to make it smooth.

Comment: Ahh, I see what's happening -- it actually added the line several times as you're not using a nested structure. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It is because of, the code is creating as many line as the objects. so there is 7 lines being created.